# Parse json output in bash script

Tags: bash

I am executing a `curl` in my `bash` script which gives my a `json` output. I saw some posts on this but most of them are using `jq` , `python` or some external tool to parse the `json` body. Is there any way to parse a `json` body without using external tools.

Comment: You really want a JSON parser in shell script that is robust enough to handle *all* JSON syntax?

Comment: Short answer is, no, not effectively.  You would either use a tool like jq in a bash script, or use a proper language, such as perl, python, ruby, ..., and use the available tools to perform the task.